# How to show the received message in chat window instantaneously?

Tags: java, android

Here I show the received message from sqlite but that will execute when oncreate method executed but I need to show the message instantaneously. Here I have added my code

```
 public static void messageHandler(final MessageMO messageMo) {

        UIHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

        UIHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                Log.e("messageHandler", messageMo.getEventTitle());
                ChatMO chatMO = new ChatMO();
                chatMO.setMessage(messageMo.getMessage());
                chatMO.setSelf(0);
                chatMO.setFromName(messageMo.getfromUserName());
                chatMO.setDate(messageMo.getDate());
                chatMO.setEvent_id(messageMo.getEventId());
                Log.e("handler", "eventid" + chatMO.getEvent_id());
                Log.e("handler", "date" + chatMO.getDate());
                listChatMessageObjectses.add(chatMO);
                 listViewMessages.setAdapter(adapter);
                Log.e("handler", "listmessage" + listChatMessageObjectses);
                 adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
    }
```

In above code the messageMo have the received message detail. Here I have added to listChatMessageObjecs list.

This is my oncreate method

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        int position = 1;
        eventMO = (EventMO) getIntent().getParcelableExtra("eventMo");

        setContentView(R.layout.chat_main);
        context = getApplicationContext();
        String message = "";



        DatabaseHelper dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
        inputMsg = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputMsg);
        listViewMessages = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view_messages);
        Log.e("oncreate", "listmessageobject" + listChatMessageObjectses);

        final long eventId = eventMO.getEventId();
        Log.e("oncreate", "eventId" + eventId);
        List<ChatMO> chatMOs = dbHelper.getGroupChatMessageForEvent(eventId);
        Log.e("oncreate", "chatMOs" + chatMOs);
        for (ChatMO chatMO1 : chatMOs) {
            chatMO1.getMessage();
            chatMO1.getEvent_id();
            chatMO1.getFromName();
            int messageType = chatMO1.getMessage_type();
            chatMO1.getDate();
            chatMO1.isSelf();
            if (messageType == 0) {
                chatMOs1.add(chatMO1);
            }


        }
        Log.e("oncreate", "listmessage" + chatMOs1);

            chatMOs1.addAll(listChatMessageObjectses);
         if(message != null)
        //listChatMessageObjectses.addAll(chatMOs1);
        Log.e("oncreate", "listmessage" + listChatMessageObjectses);

        Log.e("oncreate", "chatMOS1" + chatMOs1);
        adapter = new MessagesListAdapter(context, chatMOs1);

        Log.e("oncreate", "adapter" + adapter);
        //adapter functionality added for show the previous chat list of event/invite
        listViewMessages.setAdapter(adapter);
        sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(Constants.SHARED_PREFERENCE_NAME, context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        // by default first primary user is current user in sql lite
        // user table
        userMO = dbHelper.getUserData(1);
```

Here I am using chatMOs1 list in adapter. Here I have added send button onclick listener

```
 sendButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                ChatMO chatMO = new ChatMO();
                chatMO.setMessage_type(Constants.MESSAGE_TYPE_MSG);
                chatMO.setMessage(inputMsg.getText().toString());
                chatMO.setSelf(1);
                chatMO.setIs_delete(0);
                chatMO.setFromName("");
                //date and time function is added here
                chatMO.setDate(DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date()));
                chatMO.setEvent_id(eventId);
                Log.e("groupchat", "chatMO" + chatMO.getEvent_id());
                DatabaseHelper dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
                long RowId = dbHelper.insertGroupChatMessage(chatMO);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "message row id for user message" + RowId, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.e("sendbutton", "before listchatmessage");
                chatMOs1.add(chatMO);
                Log.e("sendbutton", "listmessage" + listChatMessageObjectses);
                //Log.e("sendbutton","after");
                adapter = new MessagesListAdapter(context, chatMOs1);
                listViewMessages.setAdapter(adapter);
                // adapter = new MessagesListAdapter(context,listChatMessageObjectses);

                Log.e("sendbutton", "after listview messages");
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                messageMO.setMessage(inputMsg.getText().toString());
                messageMO.setRingeeUserId(userMO.getRingeeUserId());
                messageMO.setMobileNumber(userMO.getMobileNumber());
                messageMO.setEventId(eventId);
                Log.e("sendbutton", "eventid" + messageMO.getEventId());
                messageMO.setEventTitle(eventMO.getText());
                //messageMO.setEventTitle(eventMO.getText());
                messageMO.setfromUserName(userMO.getUserName());
                messageMO.setMessageType(Constants.MESSAGE_TYPE_MSG);
                messageMO.setDate(DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date()));


                Log.e("groupchat", "message" + messageMO);
```

Here the chatMO send message detail from sender and  messageMO have the detail of received message detail .

Here I need to show the message instantaneously in chat window. Can you please any one tell me how to fix it?
Thanks in advance